# shorthand condition in razor webgrid

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have set uo shorthand condition in webgrid like this but it doesn't work, pls help

```
grid.Column("sold", format: @(item.sold == 1?"Yes":"No")),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a view model please. Add a property to your view model that will be responsible for formatting this value:

```
public string FormattedSold
{
    get
    {
        return sold == 1 ? "Yes" : "No";
    }
}
```

and then bind the column to this property:

```
grid.Column("FormattedSold"),
```

And if you don't want to use view models and turn your views into spaghetti code, go ahead, be my guest:

```
grid.Column(
    "sold", 
    format: @<text>@(item.sold == 1 ? "Yes" : "No")</text>
),
```